# user profile service issue on SharePoint 2010 environment

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, user-profile-service

on our test environment, user profile service was not working. When we checked, there was no connection between AD and SharePoint. And also "Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service" was not started on Services and "User Profile Synchronization service" was stopped status on Central Administration.

for resolving issue, we think, we need to create connection between them. But our questions, can we give same domain connection which are using on Production environment? Means for example on Production, we had given connection with "Google" domain. So Test environment also same "Google" domain with same service account can we create connection? (or) is there any effect on Production if we use same domain connection on Test environment?

After making connection, Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service and User Profile Synchronzation service will be start?

is there any other process do we need to follow?

SP experts, Please clarify us.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any effect on the domain if you pass the same it(google) in the synchronization connection across environments.

**It's a one way sync, not a two way , between the synchronization connection and SharePoint UPS.**

The only thing will be that the **User profiles** and the **User profile properties** will be same in the User profile service applications in both the environments (Production and test) in your case.

This is also the ideal way because you would like to have consistency in your User profile service application across environments .

The sync is always from Active Directory to SharePoint UPS not the other way , so in no way can your domain get affected .

**Answering to your next question -**

Yes, the FIM and the Profile synchronization should start but if at all it gets stuck at Starting or Stopping you can follow the blog below to resolve the issue .

> https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/09/user-profile-synchronization-service-stuck-at-starting.html

Answer (score 0):

You must start the User Profile Synchronization service and Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service to configure a user profile sync connection and make your user profile service work.

Try to start the two services and configure your user profile service application according to this [article](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vk_3ZYde88E

If you have issue on starting the two service, check the link kamdar provide and the following articles for troubleshooting. Return with more information about your issue will help community members to find the solution for you.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/gg750257(v=office.14)

Also check the uls log and windows evnet log